# BATCH - How to get only a single line from a multi-line command output

Tags: windows, batch-file, batterylevel

The "Battery" icon in my Status Bar doesn't work, and I use a Windows Batch-Script to check the battery level. (I don't want a fix for the icon.) But, the output is kind of ugly, with no spaces and a plain number on the next line.
**So, How can i convert**

```
EstimatedChargeRemaining
83
```

**to**

```
Battery Level is at 83
```

**(Or anything of the sort.)**

P.S: The command I use is `WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me, and is a modification of **@npocmaka**'s answer (Thanks, npocmaka).

```
FOR /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%A in (
    'wmic PATH Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining  /Format:list ^| FINDSTR "[0-9]"'
)DO (echo Battery Level is at %%B)
```

What I have changed:
`FINDSTR` Converts output from *Unicode* to *ANSI* for parsing by `FOR /F`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `subprocess` & `re` module.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import subprocess
s = subprocess.check_output("WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining")
print("Battery Level is at {0}".format(re.findall("\d+", s)[0]))
```

**Output:**

```
Battery Level is at 83
```

Comment: how to stop it from quitting?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand?

Comment: When i save it as .py format, and run file, it quits in ~3 seconds. What is the Python command to wait 10 seconds?

Comment: `import time   time.sleep(10)` ?

Comment: New Error `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object` Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining /format:value') do (
   for %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"
)

echo Battery Level is at %EstimatedChargeRemaining%
```

Comment: An Error Comes: `" not definedariable "
" not definedariable "
" not definedariable "
" not definedariable "
" not definedariable "
Battery Level is at`. What to do?

Comment: @Suda - Are you using this over a laptop? If the computer is not a laptop it wont work.

Comment: I am using a HP Laptop. The plain WMIC command usually works, but your version with the *for* command isn't working.